# RemoteDroid connection problem

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-2, remote-control

Has anyone tested the [remotedroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.joshsera&feature=search_result) app? I tried (on windows xp and samsung galaxy 2), installed both server app and android app, but nothing happens. Are there any more settings I should make? Thanks.

Comment: could you maybe post the steps you've taken so far? this isn't quite enough to follow the process and find the problem or a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you have Java Runtime Environment installed (version 1.5 or higher) and try running the server program from the .bat file instead of the .jar file. Then check your software firewalls if they have blocked the application from acting as a server, and finally check your router for port redirection (UDP, 57110) if you have a NAT setup between your Wi-Fi access point and the machine acting as a server. Also it could be worthwhile to check that the IP of the PC hasn't changed since you checked it last, or if you can make it static.